# Dynamic menu breadcrumb for custom Drupal form

Tags: forms, routes, breadcrumbs

We have a form developed using form API in Drupal 7. Based on taxonomyID & nodeID in URL, the form fields will be pre-filled. I want to display the taxonomy term & node title in menu breadcrumb. The taxonomyID & nodeID will be dynamic.

For example:
URL = /tweaks/tryityourself/**{taxonomyID}**/**{nodeID}**

Expected menu breadcrumb:
Home >> **Contact Us** >> **Add new Contact us** >> Try it Yourself

In above example,
Contact Us = Taxonomy term
Add new Contact us = Node title

Can you please give your suggestion?

Comment: Try to state what you have already tried to achieve this, this is not a one-answer question.

Comment: @PanChrono I tried the code given here, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7. And it works as expected.

`code`<?php
// Build Breadcrumbs
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l('Topics', 'taxonomy/term/1');
$breadcrumb[] = %1 ;

// Set Breadcrumbs
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
?>

Comment: @PanChrono Do you have any other suggestion apart from this? Please note, my site doesn't have a custom theme or template files. It's using D7's default Bartik theme.

Comment: I am confused by the taxonomy term title and node title. Is "Add new contact us" really the title of a node? Does not really make sense to me. Also, what should be the urls of the breadcrumb items? If you can clarify I might have a solution.